# Зірки "краще" не знайти чи зірки "кращої"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Сьогодні зустрівся з сувенірним магнітом, на якому було написано:

> *І сьогодні, і завжди
>
>    Зірки краще не знайти.*

Мені здалося, що слово "краще" в неправильному відмінку. На мою думку правильно мало би бути "кращої".

Ось питання. Це калька з російської, можливо, чи звичайна помилка? Чи, можливо, тут все правильно написано?

[image]

Comment: "Зірки кращої нема" на мій погляд найбільше підходить. Хоча не в римується. Вираз з магнітика говорить, що зірки краще не знаходити, чим знаходити.

Comment: рима втрачається, проте, якщо замінити саме на "зірки кращої нема", то буде збережено віршовий розмір :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Тут ліпше послуговуватися словом *кращої*. *Краще* може бути прислівником, що характеризує дію, а не предмет, тому тут не пасує (["Словник української мови"](http://sum.in.ua/s/krashhe) визначає *краще* як вищий ступінь порівняння до прислівників *гарно, добре*). Або ж прикметником, але на означення іменника середнього роду, наприклад, *Це кіно краще.* Прикметник вищого ступеня матиме тут закінчення -а, -ої (*краща, кращої*) - див. [правила творення ступенів порівняння якісних прикметників](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/morfologija_i_pravopis/stupeni_porivnjannja_jakisnikh_prikmetnikiv_i_tvorennja_jikh/6-1-0-101).

З римою можна щось вигадати, хоч би й таке:

> *І сьогодні, і завжди
>
>   Не знайти зорі, як ти.*

(Примітивно, але все-таки).

Comment: Я, коли в дитинстві чув рекламу «*Jillette — [най]краще для чоловіків*», інтерпретував слово «*[най]краще*» саме як прислівник, а не як прикметник, тобто сприймав це не як «*Jillette — найкращий серед усіх чоловічих товарів для гоління*», а як «*Jillette більше підходить чоловікам, аніж жінкам чи дітям*» — що викликало в мене подив через очевидну банальність фрази (про існування жіночих бритв або необхідність у певних випадках брити голову дітям я тоді, звісно, не знав).

Comment: @sasha, ще можна інтерпретувати якось _«найкраще з того всього, що взагалі було придумане для чоловіків»_ (тобто не тільки товарів [ч.р.], а ще інших речей), але це аж настільки претензійно, що аж неправдоподібно :)

Comment: "Тут ліпше послуговуватися словом кращої". - Неправильно. Тут СЛІД НЕОДМІННО вживати форми "кращої". "Краще" в цьому контексті - прикрий, потворний московізм.

Comment: @ІгорБурковський Я переніс вашу відповідь у коментар через те що вона відповідає на вже існуючу відповідь. На цьому сайті "відповідь" призначена для відповідей на питання. Для уточнення інших відповідей використовуються коментарі. Дякую!

Answer (score 1):

Додам до [іншої відповіді](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/470), що «зірки краще не знайти» можна сприйняти як «краще тобі не знаходити зірку» (мовляв, це може мати якісь неприємні наслідки абощо). Тобто — аналогічно до фрази «краще кохати і втратити кохання, ніж взагалі ніколи не любити» — сприйняти *краще* прислівником. Тому приєднуюся до першої відповіді: ліпше — а, може, навіть і слід неодмінно — писати *кращої* замість *краще*.

*Оновлення:* При пошуку слова *краще* в [корпусі української мови MOVA.info](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) (розробленому співробітниками лабораторії комп'ютерної лінгвістики Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка) я не знаходжу навіть одиничних траплянь слова *краще* в ролі прикметника чоловічого або жіночого роду, чи множини, в українській літературі (лише в ролі прислівника або прикметника середнього роду). Тому, напевне, лінгвіст Ігор Бурковський у [своєму коментарі](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/440#comment4826_470) цілком мав рацію — використання форми *кращої* в цьому випадку є не лише ліпшим, а **обов'язковим**, а *краще* в цьому випадку є прикрим **росіянізмом**.